# Cannot decrypt encrypted text through BasicTextEncryptor?

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I am using BasicTextEncryptor Class to text encryption and decryption text.

While executing the class file I am getting an exception

> Exception in thread "main" org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: Encryption raised an exception. A possible cause is you are using strong encryption algorithms and you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine
>       at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.handleInvalidKeyException(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:1073)
>       at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.encrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:924)
>       at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.encrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:642)
>       at org.jasypt.util.text.StrongTextEncryptor.encrypt(StrongTextEncryptor.java:107)
>       at com.newposition.util.TestJascrypt.main(TestJascrypt.java:45)

I have refer some of the solution blog but still not able to sorted out the issue.

I have copied the policy jar file in the **/jre/lib/security/**. 
Nut still I am getting the exception.

Can any one please help me.

Below is my encryptor class.

```
 package com.myproject.util;
 import java.io.IOException;

 import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor;
 import org.jasypt.util.binary.BasicBinaryEncryptor;
 import org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor;
 import org.jasypt.util.text.StrongTextEncryptor;
 public class TestJascrypt {

 public static StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();

 public static BasicBinaryEncryptor binaryEncryptor = new BasicBinaryEncryptor();

 public static void main(String []sene) throws IOException{

    StrongTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new StrongTextEncryptor();
    textEncryptor.setPassword("abcd");
    String myEncryptedText = textEncryptor.encrypt("abcd");
    String plainText = textEncryptor.decrypt(myEncryptedText);
    System.out.println(plainText +"    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@"); 
    }

 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you overwritten both policy JAR files in your JRE / JVM with the ones from the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files download?

Comment: hi @gar Yes I have overwritten those to policy jar files. 
I have found one new clue  whether issue is with OS or something I cant find out. While I run that in Ubuntu that is working perfectly fine. but in windows it is not working all the Time it is displaying exception.

Comment: This is the error you get when the policy files haven't been applied, so somehow they're not being picked up. Would it be possible that a different JRE / JVM is being used on the windows machine than you think? You should be able to confirm the running java instance using Task Manager (processes tab - right click on java and select 'properties')